# Check overflow in power implementation

Tags: java, overflow, pow

It's a common interview question to [implement the power function](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=14959760). I'm wondering what the fastest way is to find out if overflow happens (using log function is too slow). 
Is it a good way to say

```
double tempMult= aAbs*aAbs;
if (tempMult >= aAbs) 

   tempAnswer = pow(tempMult, bAbs / 2);

else
//overflow
```

Comment: It is tempting to say yes, however the behavior of an overflow is undefined here.  Does it simply take the modulo of the MAX_NUMBER?  Does it truncate, potentially resulting in a negative number?  Does it throw a Java-style exception?  How have you defined aAbs and bAbs?  More descriptive variable names is a great way to self-document.

Comment: Java returns infinity when overflow happens in Math.pow function (e.g. Math.pow((Double.MAX_VALUE),2) )

Comment: Glib moment: "What does that have to do with the price of tea in China?".  That's the result returned, but that isn't the result of the actual MATH.

Comment: Overflow where? "aAbs * aAbs" may already create an overflow, without even going into pow(). What are the variable types?

Comment: You are right Durandal, the check has to be done before calling pow

Comment: jgitter, Please follow the link in the question for whole code. For multiplication, java truncates (for integers, it truncates MSBs after 32 bit, the result of truncate might be a negative number. Integer.MAX_VALUE*2 = -2)

Answer (score 1):

Floating point types do not overflow, they "flush to infinity" (the behavior is defined/mandated by IEEE-754). The overflow condition is detectable at machine code level (through a processor flag etc.), but thats obviously not an option for high level languages. You can only check that the result is not +/- infinity (Double.isInfinite(arg)).

So the code you show will *never* detect an overflow for aAbs*aAbs; except for a NaN argument:

If aAbs is negative and overflows, tempMult becomes +INFINITY,
if aAbs is positive and overflows, tempMult becomes +INFINITY,
if aAbs is already +/- INFINITY tempMult becomes +INFINITY and
if aAbs is NaN tempMult becomes NaN also. The expression can also underflow (aAbs * aAbs == 0), if aAbs is sufficiently small, but that shouldn't cause any issues.

In the NaN case, "(tempMult >= aAbs" evaluates as false, so the only case you detect as overflow is the NaN argument, which is probably also not what you intended.

This should give sane results, *but* it will *still* not handle arguments of value +/-INFINITY or NaN (you would need to explicitly handle these if desired):

```
double tempMult= aAbs*aAbs;
if (Double.isInfinite(tempMult)) {
    // overflow
} else {
    answer = pow(tempMult, bAbs / 2);
}
```

So to handle *all* eventualities:

```
if (Double.isNaN(aAbs) {
    // NaN
} else if (Double.isInfinite(aAbs)) { 
    // Infinity argument
}
double tempMult= aAbs*aAbs;
if (Double.isInfinite(tempMult)) {
    // overflow
} else {
    answer = pow(tempMult, bAbs / 2);
}
```